# a set of equations

Tags: equations

There is no error in the following, but I think there is a standard format in writing such sets of equations. If it is possible to make amendments, then I'd be happy to be informed.

```
\begin{equation}
\setlength\arraycolsep{1.5pt}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 &\mathcal{C}_{1}+&&\mathcal{C}_{2}+&&\mathcal{C}_{3} &= & 0\\
 a&\mathcal{C}_{1}+&b&\mathcal{C}_{2}+&c&\mathcal{C}_{3} &= & - 
 (\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}+\beta_{1}\beta_{2}+\gamma_{1}\gamma_{2})\\
 a^{2}&\mathcal{C}_{1}+&b^{2}&\mathcal{C}_{2}+&c^{2}&\mathcal{C}_{3} &= 
 &-2a\alpha_{1} \alpha_{2}-2b\beta_{1} \beta_{2}-2c\gamma_{1} \gamma_{2}
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `cases` you get for free some more spacing between the rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\cC}{\mspace{2mu}\mathcal{C}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{ *{3}{ r>{{}}c<{{}} } c }
     \cC_{1} &+&      \cC_{2} &+&      \cC_{3} &=& 0\\
    a\cC_{1} &+&     b\cC_{2} &+&     c\cC_{3} &=&
  -(\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}+\beta_{1}\beta_{2}+\gamma_{1}\gamma_{2})\\
a^{2}\cC_{1} &+& b^{2}\cC_{2} &+& c^{2}\cC_{3} &=&
  -2a\alpha_{1} \alpha_{2}-2b\beta_{1} \beta_{2}-2c\gamma_{1} \gamma_{2}
\end{array}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The `>{{}}c<{{}}` trick is usual for having columns with operation or relation symbols that get correctly spaced.

Since `\mathcal{C}` is not really thought for receiving coefficients, I added a small space to avoid shape conflicts. I've never seen unknowns named that way.

[image]